# How can i emulate mouse input ? e.g. set MouseButtons State?

Tags: c#, mouse, kinect

How can I set mouse buttons state in C#?

My application control mouse by gestures and I need to set mouse leftbutton state to pressed base on my gesture.

Comment: What are we talking about here? A WinForms application? A Windows Service? A Console App? Do you only want to invoke click events locally in your own app, or send mouse events globally to every application on the desktop? What kind of "gestures" are you talking about? Kinect? Mouse gestures? Touch events? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET provides mouse event handlers that consume events raised when Form controls are interacted with. You can also simulate mouse behavior within the Forms control context.

[.NET mouse events in windows forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx)

For Global/Out of Windows Forms mouse events and simulate mouse functions, you will need a global mouse hook library/dll such as:

[global mouse hook and mouse simulator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library)